# Merge two questions: opinions

Tags: discussion

[This](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/11055/conversation-language-translation) question almost overlaps with an earlier asked question ([this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/whats-the-best-way-to-show-a-foreign-language-in-a-manuscript)) where Lauren's answer also serves as an answer to the newer question.

Should these questions be merged? Opinions? Mods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging generally makes sense when both questions have answers, and the answers could apply to either question.

The first of the two questions you linked to is a duplicate of the second question; I've closed the first one, which already had a couple of close votes, as it has no answers. (It's also not a very well-written question.)